# Issue With localeCompare (Sorting XML By Date)

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, html

I am trying to build a simple page that displays the formatted and sorted contents of an XML file following what is outlined in this post: [Sorting XML results by date using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149227/sorting-xml-results-by-date-using-jquery)

However, I am getting an error of: ***Object doesn't support property or method 'localeCompare'***

**Here is my XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blog>
  <article>
    <id>1</id>
    <author>eat-sleep-code</author>
    <title><![CDATA[The first article.]]></title>
    <content>
      <![CDATA[
        This is my first article in my test site.
      ]]>
    </content>
    <createdate>2014-05-09</createdate>
  </article>
  <article>
    <id>2</id>
    <author>eat-sleep-code</author>
    <title><![CDATA[The second article.]]></title>
    <content>
      <![CDATA[
        This is my second article in my test site.  This article's create date is actually earlier.
      ]]>
    </content>
    <createdate>2014-05-08</createdate>
  </article>
</blog>
```

**Here is my JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
        url: "blog.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {

            var items = [];

            $(xml).find("article").each(function () {

                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var title = $(this).find('title').text();
                var content = $(this).find('content').text();
                var date = $(this).find('createdate').text();

                var articleText = '<h2 class="blog-title">' + title + '</h2>';
                articleText = '<span class="blog-date">' + date + '</span>';
                articleText += '<div class="blog-content">' + content + '</div>';
                        items.push($('<article />', {
                    'class' : 'items',
                    text : articleText,
                                'data-d' : new Date(date).getTime()
                            }));
                    });

                    items.sort(function(a, b) {
                        return $(a).data('d').localeCompare($(b).data('d'));
                    });

                    $.each(items, function(idx, itm) { 
                        $('#blog').append(itm); 
                    });
            }
    });
});
```

I double checked and both $(a).data('d') and $(b).data('d') both return the correct date in Epoch format.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my JavaScript to match the following.

Note that I converted the two date values to String before hand.   I am not sure how example I was working off from didn't have to do that.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
        url: "blog.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {

            var items = [];

            $(xml).find("article").each(function () {

                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var title = $(this).find('title').text();
                var content = $(this).find('content').text();
                var date = $(this).find('createdate').text();

                var articleText = '<h2 class="blog-title">' + title + '</h2>';
                articleText = '<span class="blog-date">' + date + '</span>';
                articleText += '<div class="blog-content">' + content + '</div>';
                        items.push($('<article />', {
                    'class' : 'items',
                    html : articleText,
                                'data-d' : new Date(date).getTime()
                            }));
                    });

                    items.sort(function(a, b) {
                        var aVal = new String($(a).data('d'));
                        var bVal = new String($(b).data('d'));
                        return bVal.localeCompare(aVal);
                    });

                    $.each(items, function(idx, itm) { 
                        $('#blog').append(itm); 
                    });
            }
    });
});
```